# Rank of $I_m - X_{m \times m}$ given rank of $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, matrix-rank

I have a matrix $X_{m\times m}$ which is idempotent and has $rank(X) = n < m$. I have for some time now been trying to calculate $rank(I_m - X)$ but have been unable to do so. I should be able to get an exact value for the rank, not just an inequality.

I have established or know the following things.

1. By the rank-nullity theorem $rank(I-A) + dim$ $\mathcal{N}(I - A) = m$.
2. $\forall v \in \mathcal{N}(X)$ we have $(I-X)v = Iv - Xv = Iv = v$.
3. $\forall v \in \mathcal{N}(I - X)$ we have $(I-X)v = 0 \implies Iv = v = Xv$. Together with point 2 this implies that $\mathcal{N}(I-X) \cap \mathcal{N}(X) = {0}$.
4. $dim$ $\mathcal{N}(A) = m - n$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If $X$ is idempotent it must have full rank... assuming by idempotent you mean $X^2 = I$.

Comment: By idempotent I mean $X^2 = X$. Is that the wrong term for this?

Comment: You're right, I'm confused

Comment: If $X$ is idempotent then $(X - I)(X) = 0$ so it can only have eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ and also it must be semisimple (diagonalizable).  So you can diagonalize it, say with $a$ 0's and $b$ 1's.  The rank of $X$ is $b$.  Then the rank of $X - I$ is $a$.  So the answer is
$$rank(X) + rank(I - X) = m$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is idempotent then $(X - I)(X) = 0$ so it can only have eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ and also it must be semisimple (diagonalizable).  So you can diagonalize it, say with $a$ 0's and $b$ 1's.  The rank of $X$ is $b$.  Then the rank of $X - I$ is $a$.  So the answer is
$$rank(X) + rank(X - I) = m$$

Comment: Follow-up question: I read that a matrix $X_{m \times m}$ is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. If there are only two distinct eigenvalues can this criterion be met?

Comment: The reason you know it is diagonalizable is because $(X - I)(X)$ has only simple roots (i.e. multiplicity one exponents on the factors).  Here's a kind of ad hoc argument I'm sure can be improved upon.  Let $v$ be any vector.  Write $v = (Xv) + (v - Xv)$.  I claim that $v - Xv$ is an eigenvector of 0 and $Xv$ is an eigenvector of 1 -- these are both checked by the identity $(X - I)Xv = 0$.  This is essentially the content of the other answer, btw.

Comment: Just to be extra clear in general two distinct eigenvalues does not imply diagaonlizable (counterexample, take the "block sum" of two non-diagonalizable matrices with only one eigenvalue each).  What does imply it is that the minimal polynomial for $X$ has only simple (multiplicity one) roots.  Since $(X - I)X =0$ the minimal polynomial must divide that so it can only have simple roots.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is an imdepotent of rank $n$ then $I_m - X$  is a idempotent of rank $m-n$.

For the rank: chech that we  have a direct sum decomposition $$\mathbb{R}^m =X(\mathbb{R}^m) \oplus ( I_m - X)(\mathbb{R}^m)$$

Comment: Does this essentially mean that $\mathcal{C}(X) \cup \mathcal{C}(I-X) = \mathbb{R}^m$? I'm not familiar with direct sum decompositions.

Comment: Oh, it means that every vector $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ ( or whatever your vector space is) has a unique decomposition as $$u = Xv + ( I-X) w$$ The existence of a decomposition is clear $$u = X u + (I-X)u$$ It's the uniqueness where we use the fact that $X$ is an idempotent.